# How to align TextView around an ImageView?

Tags: android, textview, imageview, alignment, spannablestring

[image]

I am trying to align the TextView around ImageView. I am using the following code:

```
 private void createSpannableText(){
        TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        builder.append(this.getText(R.string.loren__ipsum__max));
        int lengthOfPart1 = builder.length();
        builder.append(" ");
        builder.append(this.getText(R.string.lorem__ipsum));
        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myImage);
        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight()); // <---- Very important otherwise your image won't appear
        ImageSpan myImage = new ImageSpan(d);
        builder.setSpan(myImage, 0, lengthOfPart1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        myTextView.setText(builder);
    }
```

But couldn't get the exact result. What shall I do? Do I need to use SpannableStringBuilder in this case or there is another way. Please help. I used this post-http://majaxandroidtips.blogspot.in/2009/06/how-to-have-few-layout-elements-wrap_17.html
to have the solution.

P.S.: I also want 6dp margin around the ImageView

Comment: nice way of asking question :)

Comment: @Debopam did you maybe manage to fix this below code for image placed on the right side?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `android.text.style.LeadingMarginSpan.LeadingMarginSpan2` interface which is available in API 8. Here is the [article](http://dev.androidteam.ru/snippets/textview/leadingmarginspan2), not in English though, translate it using your  browser. Besides you can download the source code of the example directly from [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1134234/AndroidTeam/dev/examples/MyLeadingMarginSpan2.zip).

Your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:textSize="18.0sp"
        android:id="@+id/message_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Helper class implements `LeadingMarginSpan.LeadingMarginSpan2`

```
class MyLeadingMarginSpan2 implements LeadingMarginSpan.LeadingMarginSpan2 {
    private int margin;
    private int lines;

    MyLeadingMarginSpan2(int lines, int margin) {
        this.margin = margin;
        this.lines = lines;
    }

    /* Возвращает значение, на которе должен быть добавлен отступ */
    @Override
    public int getLeadingMargin(boolean first) {
        if (first) {
            /*
             * Данный отступ будет применен к количеству строк
             * возвращаемых getLeadingMarginLineCount()
             */
            return margin;
        } else {
            // Отступ для всех остальных строк
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void drawLeadingMargin(Canvas c, Paint p, int x, int dir, 
            int top, int baseline, int bottom, CharSequence text, 
            int start, int end, boolean first, Layout layout) {}

    /*
     * Возвращает количество строк, к которым должен быть 
     * применен отступ возвращаемый методом getLeadingMargin(true)
     * Замечание:
     * Отступ применяется только к N строкам первого параграфа.
     */
    @Override
    public int getLeadingMarginLineCount() {
        return lines;
    }
};
```

Your activity code:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String text = getString(R.string.text);

        // Получаем иконку и ее ширину
        Drawable dIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
        int leftMargin = dIcon.getIntrinsicWidth() + 10;

        // Устанавливаем иконку в R.id.icon
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setBackgroundDrawable(dIcon);

        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text);
        // Выставляем отступ для первых трех строк абазца
        ss.setSpan(new MyLeadingMarginSpan2(3, leftMargin), 0, ss.length(), 0);

        TextView messageView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_view);
        messageView.setText(ss);
    }
```

And finally here a demo result:

[image]

Comment: I have implemented it. But the ImageView gets behind the text not in its actual position.

Comment: Ok. I get it. But is there a possibility to determine no. of line counts according to the height of the Image. What I mean to say is that is the lines will be determined by the height of the image. It is not possible by using dIcon.getIntrinsicHeight() because it returns the value which is greater than my no. of lines.

Comment: @Debopam I think you can get the number by using image height and text line height of textview, you can see vortex's  answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248759/how-to-layout-text-to-flow-around-an-image

Comment: @Debopam he used int lines = (int)Math.round(height / textLineHeight);

Comment: Why don't you use an ImageSpan?

Comment: This works well!  One peculiarity to note: in the function getLeadingMargin(boolean first), "first" represents lines 0..n-1 where n is the value returned by getLeadingMarginLineCount().

Comment: @K_Anas : How would this code change if I have imageview on right side and text has to align using right margin ? It's possible with this custom code, rigth ?

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the margin created to avoid the image is applied to every carriage return in the field.

Comment: @K_Anas how to change your code for image placed on the right side?

Comment: @PeriHartman hello. any idea on how to change this code for image placed on the right side of the screen?

Comment: @WahibUlHaq  did you solve this problem and manged to set this code for image placed on the right side of the screen?

Comment: @Ramona I won't even remember coz its almost a 2 year old problem :) 

But you can try and give a look at this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/8463221/1016544 and I have seen examples where people solved a similar problem using `android.text.style.LeadingMarginSpan.LeadingMarginSpan2`