# Flow textview around image

Tags: android, user-interface, kotlin, textview

I've spent hours looking for answer and have really no idea how to solve it. So let's get down to business:

There is an image and a `TextView` and I need to flow the `TextView` around the `ImageView` like this:

[image]

First possible solution woult be to use https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView but it's not extending `TextView` so this library is not suitable for me for number of reasons.

Second solution would be to use `LeadingMarginSpan.LeadingMarginSpan2` span but it affects on **each** paragraph for each n lines inside the text (like in this answer -> [How to layout text to flow around an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248759/how-to-layout-text-to-flow-around-an-image)), so I get smth like this:

[image]

But I wanted to set margin only for first n lines! Then I decided to implement `LeadingMarginSpan.Standart` and create a counter and increment it in `getLeadingMargin(first: Boolean): Int` function invocation. When the counter reach the desirable value, the function returns 0 as a margin width. And there is a fail again! Instead of filling the `TextView` lines, the text just moved left and didn't spread to the end of the view!

UPD: Yes, I've used `onGlobalLayoutListener` in here

[image]

Well, googling for another solution I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27064368/7218592
Ok, I've done everything as described and implemented the code:

```
            //set left margin of desirable width
            val params: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
            params.leftMargin = holder.imageContainerHeight!!
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, holder.mNumberAndTimeInfo!!.id)
            holder.mCommentTextView!!.layoutParams = params
            if (holder.commentTextViewOnGlobalLayoutListener != null)
                holder.mCommentTextView!!.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                        holder.commentTextViewOnGlobalLayoutListener)

            //add onGlobalLayoutListener
            holder.mCommentTextView!!.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                    if (holder.commentTextViewOnGlobalLayoutListener != null)
                        holder.commentTextViewOnGlobalLayoutListener
                    else CommentTextViewOnGlobalLayoutListener(holder,
                            SpannableString(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(
                            mView.getActivity(), commentDocument.html(), 0,
                            null, SpanTagHandlerCompat(mView.getActivity())))))`
```

My `OnGlobalLayoutListener` looks like this: `

```
class CommentTextViewOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            val holder: CommentAndFilesListViewViewHolder, val commentSpannable: Spannable) :
            ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        val LOG_TAG: String = CommentTextViewOnGlobalLayoutListener::class.java.simpleName

 override fun onGlobalLayout() {
        holder.mCommentTextView!!.viewTreeObserver.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this)

        //when textview layout is drawn, get the line end to spanify only the needed text
        val charCount = holder.mCommentTextView!!.layout.getLineEnd(Math.min(
                holder.mCommentTextView!!.layout.lineCount - 1,
                CommentLeadingMarginSpan.computeLinesToBeSpanned(holder)))
        if (charCount <= commentSpannable.length) {
            commentSpannable.setSpan(CommentLeadingMarginSpan(holder),
                    0, charCount, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        }

        //set the left margin back to zero
        (holder.mCommentTextView!!.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams).leftMargin = 0
        holder.mCommentTextView!!.text = commentSpannable
    }
}
```

`

Well, it works. But how terrible it works! As I'm using view holder pattern I have to hold a variable to the listener and remove if it is not been called and successfully removed because `onGlobalLayout` function wasn't called in time! And it is called too late, so you need to wait about 300 ms and then watch all the "reconstruction" of the `TextView` and it looks disgustingly!

So, my question is:
**How to make margins for *first* n lines in `TextView`, before it's been drawn on UI?**

Comment: I would try a different approach here, I would use a webview here and set the image and text in there

Comment: Webview is not an option because there are several custom clickable spans that I need to handle. I can't abandon them :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to layout text to flow around an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248759/how-to-layout-text-to-flow-around-an-image)

Comment: I think issue was introduced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494158/how-to-align-textview-around-an-imageview)  , possible duplication.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a suggestion that will only work with a little trial and error
This code uses a multi line Edit Text

```
        btnPrint.setOnClickListener {
        val str = """
        One
        Two
        Three
        Now click Action Button Custom SB
        """.trimIndent()
        etNews.setText(str)
    }
```

Play with the One Two values indent and trimIndent has other properties available